# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am loading the content from other local pages using $.load but i get this error in both chrome and firefox.

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience
```

This is my code

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuL", function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".main").html('<center><img src="img/loader.gif" /></center>');
    $(".main").load(e + session, function(response, status, xhr){
        if(status == "error") {
            window.location.href = '/home';
        }
    });
    return false
});
```

I googled every possibile solution but all of them lead me to the same thing, setting async to true but how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.load()` is just a simplified function of a normal `$.ajax()` call, you can use the `$.ajaxPreFilter()` to set specific options before each request is sent and before they are processed by `$.ajax()`.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});
```

By default, this is set to `true` and wont change unless you've done that somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yeah that did trick but now i get another error with dataTables, it says function is not defined !

Comment: My question is the same code base i used in different web server never comes the error?